# Jest React Mocking a div/prop within a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest to snapshot test my component that had a `div` that can be empty sometimes, and have something else in it other times, like a `<Dropdown>` component.

```
render() {
    return (
         <div>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
  }
```

I have a couple pages where the parent component passes nothing for the prop, so the `div` is empty, and other pages where the parent component passes a `<Dropdown>`. I hope this makes sense. I'm doing Containment: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Now, my test looks like this:

```
describe('<MyComponent/>', () => {
  it('renders a correct snapshot with an empty  div', () => {
    const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
    const props = {
      prop1: 'prop1',
      prop2: jest.fn(),
    };
    const tree = renderer.render(<MyComponent {...props} />);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('renders a correct snapshot with div displaying something', () => {
    jest.mock('components/common/Dropdown', () => () => (
       <div id="mockDownload">Dropdown</div>
    ));
    const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
    const props = {
      prop1: 'prop1',
      prop2: jest.fn(),
      prop3: Dropdown
    };
    const tree = renderer.render(<MyComponent {...props} />);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I don't think I'm doing it right. Basically I'm just trying to test the 2 cases, 1 where the `div` is empty and another where the `div` has something. The `Dropdown` has a bunch of things like `buttonText` and `caption` and `onSelect`, but I don't want to test those.

I tried this too:

```
  it('renders a correct snapshot with div displaying something', () => {
    const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
    const props = {
      prop1: 'prop1',
      prop2: jest.fn(),
    };

    const dropdown = <Dropdown />;

    const tree = renderer.render(<MyComponent {...props}<div>{dropdown}</div></MyComponent>);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Comment: Do you need to mock anything? The `children` are whatever you pass, so just e.g. `render(<MyComponent {...props}><div>whatever</div></MyComponent>)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hmm I tried that just now, but the snapshot is still empty. Both the test cases show an empty `<div />` still. This is what I did: 
```const tree = renderer.render(<MyComponent {...props}><div>Download</div></MyComponent>);```

Comment: Ok I got it to work with ```const tree = renderer.render(<MyComponent {...props} children={<Dropdown />} />;``` but the snapshot says 
``` <div>+     <Unknown />+   </div>``` Any idea why it says `Unknown`?

Comment: What happens when you run the last test in your question. I think this one is the closest to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to mock anything. Just render the component exactly the same way you would in application code. Your final example is close to correct. It is just missing a `>`:

```
const tree = renderer.render(<MyComponent {...props}><div><Dropdown/></div></MyComponent>);
```

You may need to [update your snapshot](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing#updating-snapshots) in order for this to pass.

Comment: Hmm even after updating the snapshot, it gives the same result:
` exports[<MyComponent/> renders a correct snapshot with div displaying something 1] = 
<WithStyles(Paper)
  elevation={1}
>
  <div>
    Download 
    Data
  </div>
  <div />
  <div>`
The empty `div` is still there.

Comment: @usershrub123 Yes in the case that `MyComponent` is not passed any children, it will render as `<div></div>`. When you you pass it some children then it will render as `<div>...whatever the children render as here...</div>`.

Comment: @usershrub123 Maybe I misunderstand what you mean. You should edit your question to show what the result is for the final code snippet.

Comment: @usershrub123 For the sake of simplifying the test, I recommend against using `<Dropdown/>`. Instead render something simpler, like `<MyComponent {...props}>This is the children</MyComponent>`.

Comment: I think it's because I have a couple `divs`. Once I set the prop explicitly, `const tree = renderer.render(<MyComponent {...props} children={'This is the children'} />;` I got it to work.

Comment: @usershrub123 That isn't the correct way to pass children. Did you try the version in my previous comment? It should produce the exact same result as explicitly setting `children=...`, but directly tests the way you will actually do it in application code.

Comment: I tried the version you gave me. But it's giving me the empty 'div' still. Here is what I tested: `render(<MyComponent {...props}><div><Dropdown /></div></MyComponent>)` the result is still `<div />` in the snapshot.

Comment: @usershrub123  The empty `<div/>` you get is probably from the `render()` method of `<Dropdown />`. This shouldn't matter for this particular test because you are testing `<MyComponent>`, not `<Dropdown>`. You should render something more simple instead. Try `<MyComponent {...props}>This is the children</MyComponent>`.